# How to center images horizontal using calc with css

Tags: jquery, css

Im building a blog section and i need to center the images, the thing is , i dont know how many images are going to be, for example if i have one, max 3 images by row, if there 4 images, the 4th needs to be down the first one...

```
img img img
img
```

Or

```
 img
```

if i have one and

```
img img
```

having two...so also i need to resize.

Already tried:

```
block-gallery.columns-3 .blocks-gallery-item img {
    width: calc((100% - 32px)/3);
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

this seems to be working but, i dont know how many img are there...do i need some js?

Comment: How about using flexbox? Or CSS grids?

Comment: I need to resize the image when for example i have only two so its go over all the container i have set to 1024px for desktop.

Comment: Just to clarify; do you want one image to be the full width if there is only one (and 50% each if there is 2) or would one image still be a third of the width?

Comment: Full witdh if only one, 50% each if only 2 and 25%? each if only 3. But always needs to stay on full witdh and be on size.

Comment: @lucasvm1980 I only saw your comment this morning (you can tag me in future by using the '@' sign. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmathias/ox70d053/) might help you out.

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks great, is there a way to center the image?, i see them justify to left. Please send the reply as answer so i can accept.